# Google Maps API Crashing (Using Android Emulator)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using `MapView` for my app, which had been working fine. Suddenly, when using my application it crashed with the following error

```
  04-06 14:03:45.084 6969-7008/info.tommarsh.testmap E/EGL_emulation: rcCreateContext returned 0
04-06 14:03:45.084 6969-7008/info.tommarsh.testmap E/EGL_emulation: tid 7008: eglCreateContext(1284): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
04-06 14:03:45.085 6969-7008/info.tommarsh.testmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 185
                                                                     Process: info.tommarsh.testmap, PID: 6969
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: 12291
                                                                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bi.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:834)
                                                                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:20825)
                                                                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:881)
```

Now every time I enter a Fragment or Activity that uses `MapView` the same exact same error occurs. Few things to note:

- This happens on every emulator I have tried (both x86 and x86_64 ABI)
- It also happens when trying to launch `MapFragment`
- I am using Maps version 10.2.1

Any help appreciated!

Comment: please post the whole Logcat error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with emulator graphics. While creating new emulator there are some option in Emulated performance. Emulated performance has three options **Automatic**, **Hardware GLES** or **Software GLES**.

Choose **Software GLES** and see the result.
-map will be a bit slower but better than having errors.

Click the link of attached picture where to choose **Emulated Performance**.

[where to choose **Emulated Performance**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjSBB.png)

Comment: This makes it it work, thanks! Now I have to figure out why Hardware GLES is not working...